# How can I add another submenu under the submenu?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, sidebar, submenu

I tried to use the same pattern in creating submenu, and its displaying but the problem is its already showing when I only trying to view the submenu

```
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li>
    <div class="iocn-link">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-collection'></i>
        <span class="link_name">Patient Information Module</span>
      </a>
      <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Patient Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Patient</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dental</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Immunization</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pediatric</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-collection'></i>
            <span class="link_name">Pediatric</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Immunization</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deworming</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Vitamins/Suppliments</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">TB Dots</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">OB</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this :
Use **JavaScript** and **CSS** for hide and show submenu on click or hover

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log(e);
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  console.log(target);
  if (target.parentElement.className.indexOf('has-submenu') > -1) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#menu {
  background: #343434;
  color: #eee;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #eeeded
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  height: 35px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

#menu li:first-child {
  border-left: none
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

#menu li:hover > a,
#menu li a:hover {
  background: #111
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.menus {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font: 12px Arial;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul.menus {
  display: block
}

#menu a.home {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu a.prett {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px
}

#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu a.prett.open::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eee transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  background: #111;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu li {
  background: #111;
}

#menu ul.menus .has-submenu a.open ~ .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a class='home' href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Menu'>Menu</a>
      <ul class='menus'>
        <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Dropdown 1'>Dropdown 1 + Sub Menu</a>
          <ul class='submenu'>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' title='Dropdown 2'>Dropdown 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title='Dropdown 3'>Dropdown 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help Akshay , it gives me new idea but the problem is when i use the na navigation bar, the sub menu are showing only when hovering instead of using the button, perhaps I'm lacking in JS?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
  arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement; //selecting main parent of arrow
    arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
  });
}
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
console.log(sidebarBtn);
sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
});
```

```css
/* Google Fonts Import Link */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: #11101d;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.close {
  width: 78px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links {
  overflow: visible;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover {
  background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link {
  display: block
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .Menu {
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .Menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu2 {
  display: none;
}

.hover-me:hover .sub-menu2 {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .Menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .Menu a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .Menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .Menu {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .Menu .link_name {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .Menu .link_name {
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .Menu.blank {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .Menu.blank {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar .profile-details {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 260px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.close .profile-details {
  background: none;
}

.sidebar.close .profile-details {
  width: 78px;
}

.sidebar .profile-details .profile-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .profile-details img {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 14px 0 12px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.close .profile-details img {
  padding: 10px;
}

.sidebar .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar .profile-details .job {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar.close .profile-details i,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .job {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .profile-details .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 260px;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.close~.home-section {
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}

.home-section .home-content {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.home-section .home-content .bx-menu,
.home-section .home-content .text {
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.home-section .home-content .bx-menu {
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.home-section .home-content .text {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 78px;
  }
  .sidebar.close {
    width: 0;
  }
  .home-section {
    left: 78px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .sidebar.close~.home-section {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="iocn-link">
    <a href="#">
      <i class='bx bx-collection'></i>
      <span class="link_name">Patient Information Module</span>
    </a>
    <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="Menu">
    <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Patient Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patient</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dental</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Immunization</a></li>
    <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">Pediatric
                            <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
                      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu2">
        <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Pediatric</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Immunization</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deworming</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vitamins/Suppliments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">TB Dots</a></li>
    <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">OB
                        <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
                      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu2">
        <li><a class="link_name" href="#">OB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pre-Natal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Post-Natal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Family Planning</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

This is my updated code

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Is this intended to be an answer? If so, some explanation is needed. See [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).